# How to use csv column headers as plot labels

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to use the three columns headers ("NODE_POT_GAUCHE_i", "NODE_LISSE_CENTER_i", "NODE_POT_DROITE_i") as labels while plotting results from an Ansys APDL analysis in my post-process python script.

What I currently do, is that when I'm plotting in my loop, I add the label manually :

```
# Parcours de tous les fichiers csv
            for i in range(len(model[idx]['asb_path'])):

                # Parcours a l'envers des indices pour positionner les graphs
                j = len(model[idx]['asb_path'])-i-1

                # Lecture du fichier csv possédant des headers
                potiso = pd.read_csv(model[idx]['potiso_path'][i], index_col=0)
                asb = pd.read_csv(model[idx]['asb_path'][i], index_col=0)

                # Plot des résultats sur un subplot de la figure créer en haut
                axs[j].plot(potiso, label='NODE_POT_ISO')
                axs[j].plot(asb['NODE_POT_GAUCHE_'+str(i+1)], label='NODE_POT_GAUCHE_'+str(i+1))
                axs[j].plot(asb['NODE_POT_DROITE_'+str(i+1)], label='NODE_POT_DROITE_'+str(i+1))
                axs[j].set_title(os.path.basename(model[idx]['asb_path'][i]))
                axs[j].set_xlabel('time(s)')
                axs[j].set_ylabel('displacement(m)')
                axs[j].legend()
                axs[j].grid(True)

            # Enregistrement au format .png
            plt.savefig(fig_path)
```

What I would like, is to automatically use the column headers from the data frame and use them as labels automatically while plotting, allowing me to change csv organization without disturbing my python post-process script.

I can't seem to find any answer to my question, I've tried different things such as letting it blank :

```
# Parcours de tous les fichiers csv
            for i in range(len(model[idx]['asb_path'])):

                # Parcours a l'envers des indices pour positionner les graphs
                j = len(model[idx]['asb_path'])-i-1
                # Lecture du fichier csv possédant des headers
                asb = pd.read_csv(model[idx]['asb_path'][i], index_col=0)

                # Plot des résultats sur un subplot de la figure créer en haut
                axs[j].plot(asb)
                axs[j].set_title(os.path.basename(model[idx]['asb_path'][i]))
                axs[j].set_xlabel('time(s)')
                axs[j].set_ylabel('displacement(m)')
                axs[j].legend()
                axs[j].grid(True)

            plt.savefig(fig_path)
```

But I'm getting the following error :

> No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.

There must be a way to extract the column's name and then input them as a label entry for my plot.
Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered me elsewhere, which leads me to share the answer here :

```
# Parcours de tous les fichiers csv
            for i in range(len(model[idx]['asb_path'])):

                # Parcours a l'envers des indices pour positionner les graphs
                j = len(model[idx]['asb_path'])-i-1
                # Lecture du fichier csv possédant des headers
                asb = pd.read_csv(model[idx]['asb_path'][i], index_col=0)

                # Plot des résultats sur un subplot de la figure créer en haut
                axs[j].plot(asb, label = list(asb.columns))
                axs[j].set_title(os.path.basename(model[idx]['asb_path'][i]))
                axs[j].set_xlabel('time(s)')
                axs[j].set_ylabel('displacement(m)')
                axs[j].legend()
                axs[j].grid(True)

            plt.savefig(fig_path)
```

The important part is :

```
axs[j].plot(asb, label = list(asb.columns))
```

or :

```
axs[j].plot(asb, label = asb.columns)
```

It basically uses the columns attribute of the data frame object. You could as well loop through every column and build the list by yourself. (more informations here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-column-names-in-pandas-dataframe/)

**I failed at using asb.columns before cause I wasn't using it as a list, that's why it wasn't working before.**

---

**EDIT:** Be careful, if there is only one column being plotted :

```
axs[j].plot(asb, label = list(asb.columns))
```

will return ['HEADER_NAME'].

and :

```
axs[j].plot(asb, label = asb.columns)
```

will return an index.

So if there is only one column you should be using :

```
axs[j].plot(asb, label = asb.columns[0])
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that if there is only one column, the legend will appear as ['HEADER'] instead of HEADER. I'm working on finding a solution.

Comment: Using axs[j].plot(asb, label = lasb.columns) and axs[j].plot(asb, label = lasb.columns[0]) if there is only one column seems to be the solution.